How does routing of requests to pods through ClusterIP service work in k8s?
Suppose I have a ClusterIP service S associated with 10 pods. When a request is routed to the service (from the ingress controller, for example) how does it get routed to a pod?
I know someone manipulates the k8s DNS to map the service name to one single pod out of the 10. I also know that that someone constantly changes this mapping to try and route traffic to all the pods at the end of the day. What I do NOT know is what k8s component exactly is that someone and more importantly - what is the logic it uses to select the pod to which the next request will be routed?
Amazingly, I could not find k8s documentation that replies to the second question. It seems the answer to the first question is kube-proxy, but I am not sure. Would be very helpful to get the exact documentation for that part also.
I use AKS. It has calico installed, if that matters.

The Service documentation talks about this in some detail.  In normal use the Service has its own single IP address and the cluster routes traffic accordingly, also Virtual IPs and Service Proxies for lower-level details.  As an application developer this mechanism doesn't usually matter to you, with the side note that the default routing isn't especially load-aware (if one replica is handling a long-running requests it can still receive other requests).

I am pretty sure I read the Service documentation and I must have missed the piece where it describes how routing to pods through the service works. Would you be able to answer with the right quote? As for the second post - I have not read it. I will and let you know here.

Yes, the second article is very different. I checked, kube-proxy running in AKS uses iptables. Hence according to that article (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#proxy-mode-iptables) the routing is random. Could you arrange your reply as the answer, so that I could credit you?
